# Facebook login not working with Parse Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login

I'v tried a lot of solutions to implement Facebook login based on the Parse SDK without success.
It seems like I'm missing something.

### Generating Facebook hash

I tried to generate the hash with this command (and many others) and password = android:

> > keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Ido\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

But it didn't work for me, every time I tried to login I got an error that the hash key is not authorized.
Putting this code in the Appliction OnCreate made the work for me (I didn't get the error anymore):

```
try {
        PackageInfo info =     getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.idob.soccertimer",     PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String sign= Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.e("MY KEY HASH:", sign);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sign, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }
```

### Application implementation

I made the adjustments for the Facebook and Parse:

Initialize in the onCreate of the Application:

> ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));

Overriding the onActivityResult method in my loginFragment:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Add meta tag:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

I use this code to login:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(getActivity(), new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        Log.e("MyApp", err.getMessage());
                    }
                    if (user == null) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                    } else if (user.isNew()) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                    }
                }
            });
```

My problem is that the LogInCallback don't call, when I try to login twice - one LogInCallback is  returned with user = null and err = null
The OnActivityResult is not called at all.

Comment: You say your using onActivityResult in your fragment which is an issue as it's an Activity method and it will never be called unless you call it. Could you post your full fragment and invoking activity.

It will be calling the Activity.onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) which is being returned by getActivity()

Also could you tell us what is being returned from err.getMessage()

Comment: My code:
Fragment - http://codeviewer.org/view/code:4478
Activity - http://codeviewer.org/view/code:4477
The err is Null! I don't have any message

Comment: You're only displaying your error when the user isn't null. Try outputting it when it is null.

if (user == null) {
                        Log.e("MyApp", err.getMessage());
                    }

Also, add onActivityResult to your activity to see if anything is being passed to it.

Comment: I found the solution! I just had to call the fragment onActivityResult from the parent activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragment's onActivityResults would not call automatically, it should be called by the activity's onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

This path looks wrong to me :

```
C:\Users\Ido. android\debug.keystore
```

I'm a linux user and can't be 100% sure on windows paths, but I'm pretty sure it should be located :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\[User Name]\.android\debug.keystore
```

or

```
C:\Users\[User Name]\.android\debug.keystore
```